# Shape versus numbers

Tags: methodology, reaction-time, recognition

Do adults recognise numbers or shapes quicker? Have there been any studies on this?

If an adult was asked to press a corresponding button when presented with a shape or number, which would they respond to quicker?

Comment: Hi Gabs, welcome at CogSci. The question you ask could be very interesting, but could you perhaps provide a little more context to the question. What are you researching and what is the relevance? In short, why would you like to know this?

Comment: The question needs further clarification. Currently, it's like asking whether humans are faster at eating or at running - the result depends on the amount of food and the distance. In similar manner the comparison of response times will depend on how "numberiness" and "shapiness" of some stimulus set is operationalized.